# html5 video not work in ios devices with react

Tags: reactjs, html5-video

I'm using react v18.2.0, in my project I upload video and show it in other page, my problem is this videos works in devices except ios devices

input file looks like this:

```
<input name='video' type='file' accept="video/mp4" id='video' ref={inputvideo} className='hidden' onChange={async (e) => {
                                            const file = e.target.files[0]
                                            formik.setFieldValue('video', file)
                                        }} onBlur={(e) => {
                                            const file = e.target.files[0]
                                            formik.setFieldValue('video', file)
                                        }} />
```

and I show it like this:

```
{video && <video ref={videoPlayer} alt={term.wordAr} preload="yes" className='w-full h-full' width='100%' height='100%'>
                                <source src={`${baseurl}/file/${video}`} type='video/mp4' />
                            </video>}
```

I'm trying to add `autoPlay loop controls muted playsInline` but also not working with me